# Занесение в select данных, которые вернул ajax запрос

Tags: php, html, javascript

Ajax запрос возвращает данные - просто слова, разделенные пробелами или каким-либо другим знаком (это не важно). Мне необходимо занести эти данные в уже существующий select. Нашел только одно решение данного вопроса: сделать так, чтобы ajax запрос возвращал уже сформированный select и я просто заменял им старый, но, как мне кажется, это решение не очень красиво. Вопрос: существует ли другое решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да тут несколько разных вариантов=)

- Вариант 1. Вспомнить про DOM и создать тегу select дополнительные дочерние теги option с нужными параметрами. Но это несколько неудобно =)
- Вариант 2. Сформировать элементы списка с помощью соответствующих специальных команд javascript.

Примерно так выглядит полное создание списка:

```
with (myselect) // select выбранный тут уже
{
   options.length = 0; // Очистить список
   options[0]= new Option('Вариант 1','1');
   options[1]= new Option('Вариант 2','2');
   options[2]= new Option('Вариант 3','3');
   selectedIndex = 0; // Выбрать активный элемент
}
```

Добавлять элемент в конец имеющегося уже списка можно так:

```
options[options.length] = new Option(...); // select выбран с помощью with тут тоже
```

Кстати, откройте для себя json и возвращайте сразу массив, чтоб не надо было его разбирать в браузере. =)

Comment: Спасибо за содержательный ответ! Мне все больше нравиться хэшкод!

Answer (score 1):

### Вчера пол дня мучал этот вопрос. Динамическое пополнение селекта, так сказать: "Оживить его".

```html
 Пункт отправки:
 <select name='ports_calck' id='ports_calck' size = '10' >
 <option value='0'></option>
 Пункт назначаения:  
 <select id="town_calck" name='town_calck' size = '10'disabled="disabled">
```

Два списка, второй заполняется после выбора данных из первого.
javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ //читаем дом
        $('#ports_calck').change(function() { //событие выбора первого пункта
            $('#town_calck').html("<option>загрузка...</option>"); // показываем что мол загружаем
            $('#town_calck').attr('disabled', true);//делаем недоступным второй список
            id_val = $('#ports_calck').val();//присваиваем значение первого списка
            $.post('get_town.php', {id: id_val}, function(data) {//запрашиваем AJAXом данные, передаем выбранный параметр
                $('#town_calck').html(data);//данные загружаем во второй список
                $('#town_calck').attr('disabled', false);//снимаем блок со второго списка
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Ajax - запрашивал данные из файла get_town.php
PHP-часть:

```php
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");#кодировка ответа
include('function.php');#инициализация подключения к базе данных
connect();#подключение к базе данных
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['id']));#прием параметра переданного AJAX-ом
$sql="
SELECT DISTINCT `tarif`.`trans` FROM `tarif`
WHERE `tarif`.`port`='".$id."'
    ORDER BY `tarif`.`trans`;"; #SQL-запрос в базу на основе выбранного параметра
$result = mysql_query($sql); #выполняем SQL запрос
$resString = '';#переменная для отправки ответа
while(list($spo_region)=mysql_fetch_row($result)){#перебираем список
    $resString .= '<option value="'.$spo_region.'">' .$spo_region . '</option>';#формируем ответ для  списка (в javascript-части его уже ждут и загружают)
};
echo $resString;#выводим результат
?>
```

---

Впринципе все... нарно самый простой вариант что удалось откопать, а со стороны посмотришь вроде и заморочено.
Короче вот. Нужно не нужно судите сами.